# Atribuir vários array a uma variável dinamicamente

Tags: php, array, aplicação-web

Olá, eu preciso atribuir vários array a uma unica variável, o valor deles todos ficarão em sequência nessa variável. Ex.:

```
$variavel = $array[0] . $array[1] . $array[2] . $array[3] . $array[4];
echo $variavel
```

Essa variável uso ela depois num IF para fazer várias comparações, como posso fazer isso sem ter que escrever infinitos array atribuídos?

Answer (score 2):

Utilize [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) para unir/concatenar os valores dos arrays

```
echo implode(array);
```

Veja o resultado: https://3v4l.org/lDbln

Sobre os `if`, se forem comparações, é melhor tratar diretamente no array.

Podes utilizar as seguintes funções:

- [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) - busca se um valor existe no array;
- [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) - filtrar o array e retornar os valores que passaram pelo filtro;
- [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) - aplica uma função e reduz um array a um único valor. As duas funções anteriores são as mais recomendadas, entretanto, caso haja necessidade, podes aplicar uma função e retornar true/false.

Comparar diretamente a string pode não trazer resultados consistentes. Não entrarei em questões de performance, pois, não há necessidade.

Comment: Deu certo! Existe alguma forma de gerar esses array? Por exemplo, gerar array1, array2, array3 e assim sucessivamente... Sei do `for` más quando tento com ele, não consigo pegar a variável que recebe os array, fora do escopo

Comment: @SulivanSantos Não entendi o questionamento. Gerar de que forma? O que você quer "criar"?

Comment: Tentarei explicar, cada posição do array guarda informações vindas do banco de dados, na logica que estou utilizando aqui eu pego a variável que recebe a concatenação de todos as posições do array, porem para isso, eu preciso expressar todas as posições do array manualmente no codigo, queria uma forma de simplificar isso, para que caso tenha por exemplo 50 posições, eu não precise escrever 50 vezes, por exemplo: `$variavel = $array[0] . $array[1] . $array[2] ... $array[49] . $array[50];`

Comment: @SulivanSantos utilize foreach. `foreach($array as $var) { echo $var; }`. Execute esse código e veja o funcionamento.

Answer (score -1):

mude:

```
echo $variavel;
```

para:

```
echo serealize($varialvel);
```

ou

```
echo json_encode($variavel);
```